# Java Dynami dispatch

Tags: java

Here i am getting problem with a code and the is :
    class Hello259     {}

```
class Lab259     {
    public static void main (String []args) {
        Object obj = new Hello259 () ;
        System.out.println (obj instanceof String) ;
        System.out.println (obj instanceof Hello259) ;
        System.out.println (obj instanceof Object) ;
        }
    }
```

and it is error  :

```
Lab259.java:5: error: incompatible types
                Object obj = new Hello259 () ;
                             ^
  required: Object
  found:    Hello259
Lab259.java:6: error: inconvertible types
                System.out.println (obj instanceof String) ;
                                    ^
  required: String
  found:    Object
Lab259.java:7: error: inconvertible types
                System.out.println (obj instanceof Hello259) ;
                                    ^
  required: Hello259
  found:    Object
3 errors
```

As we all know that "Object class " is super class of all sub class , then why it is giving such error.  Doesn't  it follow the Dynamic dispatch concept.

Comment: `System.out.println("" + obj instanceof String);`

Answer (score 0):

You have a compilation error because your referenced class `Hello259` isn't defined.